# CSS topnav alignment issue on window resize

Tags: css

I'm having a bit of trouble keeping the topnav on my Web site (if you'll see the link below, the "Home," "Archive," and "About" buttons) aligned with where I'd like to keep it on browser resizing, which is at the right edge of my banner. Originally, I had four buttons and managed to keep everything in order, but things got a little wonky after I dropped one button.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The creation of your entire site would have been 1000% easier if you'd put `width: 940px` on one of the outer containers, such as `#container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it - get your nav to be aligned to the right side, by applying the following changes to your website:

```
#container-inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 940px;
}

.topnav {
    /*Reset things that are unnecessary*/
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: static;
    /*Set things to fix the problem*/
    margin-bottom: 20px; /*This accounts for the 20px space between this and the content.*/
    float: right;
}

#content {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put the topnav inside the banner element, and use this css:

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 930px;
    height: 349px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.topnav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top:100%;
    width: 930px;
    height: 32px;
}

.topnav a{
    float: right;
}
```

The topnav will be constant margined.

Comment: This will cause the links to be ordered in the wrong order. Ex: (ABOUT, ARCHIVES, HOME) instead of (HOME, ARCHIVES, ABOUT).

Comment: yes i know, but if you add links in opposite order it fixes it.

Comment: That sounds rather counter-intuitive, semantically, and it would wreak havoc with keyboard users and screen readers.

Comment: Ok, if you dont like it, you can also clear that .topnav a  rule, and make .topnav static inline, and add replace top to margin-top:100%; and use &nbsp; between anchor tags; And change .topnav  width: auto;